# Oracle SQL Query Help needed for below

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below :

```
ID  ref num  type   time stamp
------------------------------
1   456      X      Time 1
2   456      Y      updated Timestamp
3   678      X      Time 3
4   678      Y      updated timestamp
```

I would need help in building a query that shall give me the result as below :

```
ref num    Type Time difference
------------------------------------
456         X   (Timestamp diff between Type X and Type Y for a ref num)
678         Y   (Timestamp diff between Type X and Type Y for a ref num)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, apart from asking a question here? Even the specification is vague. What if refnum 456 is updated even more times? Do you need the difference between the first and last occurrance? Or just the differences between the first with type `X` and the last with type `Y`? Or the other way around? Please read the [FAQ], and consider doing yourself a favor, and learn to specify problems and ask questions.

Comment: result contains Type Y for 678 ref_num, but type X for 456 ref_num. What is the reason for Type in resultset? How it will behave on another ref_num's?

Comment: @Ramblin'Man: see the title of the question.

Comment: ppeterka: each reference number have only two entries in table with type X and type Y. i am basically looking for reference number and the difference between the stamps for a specific reference number.

Comment: Maks: Basically each reference number have two types (x, y) and two different time stamps. i am looking for reference number and their time stamp difference.

Comment: Where is the logic for "Type" field, you're desired to get `X` for the first row, and `Y` for the second? where is the condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select t.refnum,
       (max(case when type = 'X' then timestamp end) -
        max(case when type = 'Y' then timestamp end)
       ) as TypeTimeStampDiff
from t
group by t.refnum;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for your help. i am able to get the results as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use a co-related sub-query to get the corresponding time_stamp value:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.ref_num,
       t1.type, 
       t1.time_stamp - (select max(t2.time_stamp) from the_table t2 where t2.ref_num = t1.ref_num and t2.type = 'Y') as diff
from the_table t1
where t1.type = 'X';
```

The `max()` is just a precaution in case there is more than one row with the same ref_num and `type = 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, but the According to the provided information, all I understand is

```
select t.Ref_Num,
   (case
      when Rownum mod 2 = 0 then
       'Y'
      else
       'X'
    end) type,
   max(case when type = 'Y' then t.time_stamp end) - 
       min(case when type = 'X' then t.time_stamp end)) as Typetimestampdiff
```

from Table_Name t
 group by t.Refnum;